# How to make a frame (like a data entry form or a status bar) always appear on top of other tkinter frames in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, treeview, statusbar, ttk

So, I have a small Python 3 project that should have a window composed of 3 main areas:

- Tool bar (top);
- Table/treeview with database data (center) - this table should be able to grow downwards, with scrollbars, but I still do not know how to make them work with treeview;
- Status bar (bottom).

I am also trying to add a quick data entry form that should apear on user demand right above the status bar. I think I have been able to create the main structure for this window, using pack(). The data entry form also shows up and goes away when the user clicks the proper buttons. But there are a couple of things that I don't know how to solve. The first one is that when the user resizes the window, making it smaller, the status bar and the data entry form both disappear under the table/treeview. How can I make them be always on top?

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
# encoding: utf-8

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

entryform_visible = 0


class mainWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("AppTittle")
        master.minsize(width=700, height=200)           

        def show_entryform():
            global entryform_visible
            if entryform_visible == 1:
                hide_entryform()
                return
            else:
                entryform_visible = 1
                # Form for data entry (bottom of main window)
                status_txt.set("Introducing new data...")
                self.bottomframe.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

        def hide_entryform(): 
            global entryform_visible
            self.bottomframe.pack_forget()
            entryform_visible = 0
            status_txt.set("Introduction of data was cancelled.")

        def add_register():
            hide_entryform()
            status_txt.set("New register added!")                  

        # Tool bar (buttons)
        self.topframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
        self.topframe.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
        btn_add = ttk.Button(self.topframe, text="Button1").pack(side=LEFT)
        btn_add = ttk.Button(self.topframe, text="+", width=2, command=show_entryform).pack(side=RIGHT)
        btn_add = ttk.Button(self.topframe, text="Button2").pack(side=RIGHT)

        # Data table (center area of window)
        self.mainframe = ttk.Frame(root)
        self.mainframe.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

        tree = ttk.Treeview(self.mainframe, height=25, selectmode='extended')
        tree['columns'] = ('id', 'name', 'descr')
        tree.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)
        tree.column('#0', anchor=W, minwidth=0, stretch=0, width=0)
        tree.column('id', anchor=W, minwidth=30, stretch=0, width=40)
        tree.column('name', minwidth=30, stretch=1, width=30)
        tree.column('descr', minwidth=100, stretch=1, width=200)
        tree.heading('id', text="ID")
        tree.heading('name', text="Name")
        tree.heading('descr', text="Description")

        # Data entry form
        self.bottomframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
        ttk.Label(self.bottomframe, text="Field 1").pack(side=LEFT)
        text_input_obj = ttk.Entry(self.bottomframe, width=13)
        text_input_obj.pack(side=LEFT)
        text_input_obj.focus_set()
        btn_add = ttk.Button(self.bottomframe, text="Add", command=add_register).pack(side=RIGHT)
        # We are going to pack() this later (when the user clicks the '+' button)

        # Status bar
        self.statusframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="2 2 2 2")
        self.statusframe.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
        status_txt = StringVar()
        self.statusbar = ttk.Label(self.statusframe, textvariable=status_txt).pack(side=LEFT)


root = Tk()
appwindow = mainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think i have figured out a way. I have just discovered that we can add `before=self.mainframe` to the pack() arguments. Doing that for both frames (status bar and form) they stick on top of the other layers. Now I got to find out how to get a scrollbar to work with my treeview...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The first one is that when the user resizes the window, making it
>   smaller, the status bar and the data entry form both disappear under
>   the table/treeview. How can I make them be always on top?

This has to do with how the packer works. It will start chopping off widgets when the space available is less than the space needed. It does this in the reverse order of how widgets were packed.

In this case, because the bottom frame was packed last, when you shrink the window to be too small to fit everything, pack first shrinks any windows that might have expanded to larger than their default size, and then starts chopping off widgets starting with the last widget that was packed. In this case it is `self.statusframe` that gets chopped since it was the last to be packed.

There are two ways to solve this. One is to simply reverse the order that you pack everything into the root window. The other is to initially make the tree widget very small, and then let it grow to fill the space. Since the natural size of the treeview is small, tkinter will shrink it before it starts removing widgets from view. If you do this second technique, you can use `wm_geometry` to make the window large when it starts out (otherwise the tree won't have any space to grow into)

My advice is to always group your `pack` and `grid` statements. It makes changes like this very easy, and it make visualizing your code much easier. For example, using the first technique I would move the packing of the main areas to the bottom of the function:

```
# layout the main GUI
self.topframe.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
self.statusframe.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
self.mainframe.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
```

With this, when space gets tight pack will start to chop off the tree. But since the tree is big, there's plenty to chop before it starts to disappear.

When you do this, you'll expose another problem in your layout, and that is that you don't have the treeview expanding to fill extra space in `mainframe`. You need to pack it like this:

```
tree.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
```

This brings up another problem. Namely, your popup `bottomframe` may pop up hidden. That is because pack isn't designed to work well in this sort of situation. Again, that is because `pack` will start to chop off widgets in the reverse order that they were added. Since you're adding it last, it's the first widget to get chopped off. If the user resizes the window to be smaller, packing it at the bottom may cause it to never appear.

A better solution in this specific case is to *not* use pack for this one widget. Instead, since you want it to "pop up", you can use `place`. `place` is perfect for popping up widgets on top of other widgets. The only other thing you need to do is make sure that this frame is higher in the stacking order than the statusbar, which you can do with `lift`:

```
def show_entryform():
    ...
    self.bottomframe.place(relx=.5, rely=1, anchor="s", relwidth=1.0)
    self.bottomframe.lift()
```

And, of course, use `place_forget` instead of `pack_forget`:

```
def hide_entryform(): 
    ...
    self.bottomframe.place_forget()
    ...
```

Comment: I am trying to incorporate your very clarifying tips with some of the modifications I have been making since. It's pretty straighforward, I think. I have a new doubt however. When I change `bottomframe` from `pack` to `place`, it gets placed over the packed `statusframe`, that I want to always be visible (right at the bottom of the window). Should I return to `pack`, or would you still recomend `place` for this frame with some kind of adjustment? I am trying to make `bottomframe` show up right above the `statusframe`.

Comment: @Victor: there are many ways to accomplish what you want. I didn't know if you wanted it over the statusbar or not. The easiest, quite honestly, is to switch to `grid`, because it's easier to hide and restore widgets since `grid` remembers how a widget was orginally added to the display. That being said, you can use `place` to place the popup above the status window (or at the bottom of the middle window). Read the documentation -- there are options to place a widget relative to another widget (look for the `in_` option.

Comment: I was able to get it right using `place`, like this: `self.bottomframe.place(in_=self.statusframe, relx=1,  y=0, anchor="se", relwidth=1, bordermode="outside")`. Seems to be working fine, and comparing to my earlier `pack` based form, I somehow got rid of a strange blink that was happening when the `bottomframe` was shown on screen. :)